# Using Low Replace with {site_url} not working

Tags: low-replace

I'm having a problem making this Low Replace statement work. Basically I'm trying to use Low Replace to change any local URLs for images to use our CDN URL. I am using the {site_url} EE variable and a global variable I created called {cdn}. So when I ran the following code, the replacement didn't happen.

```
{exp:low_replace find="{site_url}images/" replace="{cdn}/images/"}
     <img src="http://www.domain.com/images/test.png" />
{/exp:low_replace}
```

If I try and just put in the actual site URL in the find parameter, then it does work. But I don't want to do that since it makes switching between environments with different URLs a hassle.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

{site_url} is a late parsed variable, i.e. after tags are parsed. That means Low Replace will look for the literal string "{site_url}" rather than its content.

You'll have to use the actual var's value here.

Comment: Thanks for your response Low! I didn't see this till just now, for some reason I didn't get a notification.

So I tried creating another global variable "{gv-site}" with the site URL, but it still wasn't replacing.

{exp:low_replace find="{gv-site}images/" replace="{cdn}/images/"}
     <img src="http://www.domain.com/images/test.png" />
{/exp:low_replace}

For some reason it does use the {cdn} value for replace, but not for find.

Comment: Or I guess to put it another way, how can I have some sort of variable for the "find" URL part of the tag? I'm trying to avoid having to make any template changes when switching between environments. Is there possibly a way for me to modify the plugin to run after variables (or global variables) are parsed?